# in django how can i reverse to that page when info submitted

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

```
class ModelCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Message
    fields=['message']

    template_name = "page.html"
    
    succes_url = reverse='page'
```

No URL to redirect to.  Either provide a url or define a get_absolute_url method on the Model.
this is error but if i put get absolute url reverse going detail page

Answer (score 0):

You need to be change `success_url` like this...

```
class MyModelCreate(CreateView):
    model = MyModel
    success_url = reverse('index')

    ---------- OR ------------
    success_url = '/index/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `get_success_url` as described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.get_success_url) in Django documentation:

```py
from django.urls import reverse

class ModelCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Message
    fields=['message']

    template_name = "page.html"

    def get_success_url(self):
        """Return the URL to redirect to after processing a valid form."""
        return reverse('page')
```

You can also check [this page](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/4.0/django.views.generic.edit/CreateView/) if you have similar questions regarding this class based view.